# Approximation Algorithm question

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

Define an independent set of a graph $G = (V, E)$ to be a subset $S$ of vertices such that $V-S$ is a vertex cover of $G$. Is every $2$-approximation algorithm for finding a minimum vertex cover also a $2$-approximation algorithm for finding a maximum independent set?

I have read about approximation algorithms, but could relate vertex cover problem to independent set. Do you have any suggestions on why such algorithm can be found or not?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem? I would really appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I am concerned, unless P=NP there can't be a constant-ratio approximation algorithm for the Maximum Independent set problem [On the Complexity of Approximating the independent Set Problem](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/TOPICS/pcp/bs1992.pdf) . So to answer your question:

No.

A 2-approximation algorithm for the Minimum Vertex Cover does not guarantee for an Independent set having at least half the size of the Maximum Independent set. Suppose $S$ is an optimal vertex cover and has size $\geq |V|/2$. Then a 2-approximation algorithm is only guaranteed to give a vertex cover of size $|V|$. Hence one does not obtain a non-trivial independent set by complementing the approximate vertex cover.